# Create Foreach loop inside List<Tuple<string, string>>

Tags: tuples

I want to loop through my list and create Tuple adding items from that list. I can't make it working

```
var arr = "PAR: Parent,SVE: School visit from an engineer,SCI: Science teacher";    
var query = arr.Split(',').Select(x => x.Split(':'))
                         .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);   

var list = query.ToList();  

    var tupleList = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
{    
foreach (var i in list )
        {
            Tuple.Create(i.Key, i.Value);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is

```
var tupleList = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
foreach (var i in list)
{
    tupleList.Add(Tuple.Create(i.Key, i.Value));
}
```

Collection initializer such as

```
var tupleList = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
{
    foreach (var i in list)
    {
        Tuple.Create(i.Key, i.Value);
    }
}
```

will not work.